# Facebook comments are missing

Tags: facebook, comments

I have a Magento store with Facebook comments: http://eiradyrebutikk.no/kong-wobbler

Under the tab "omtaler", when someone comments, the comment disappears. I can still see the comment on the moderator page in Facebook.

Anyone else got this problem?

Comment: Post the code where you embed the facebook app. Maybe you're leaving something out.

Comment: Its an extension for magento. But i can get the code from the extension file

Comment: The code is to large to post here it says

Comment: But here is just some of it:</script>
  <div class="fblike">
   <fb:comments xid="<?php echo $this->getXid()?>" href="<?php echo $link ?>" callbackurl="<?php echo $this->getUrlForntEnd(); ?>"  numposts="<?php echo $this->numberOfCommment()?>" width="<?php echo $this->widthOfCommmentBox() ?>" publish_feed="<?php echo $this->publicFeed() ?>"  reverse="<?php echo $this->isReserveOrdering() ?>" simple="<?php echo !$this->isRoundedBox() ?>" css="<?php echo $this->getCssUrl() ?>" migrated="1">
    <fb:title></fb:title>
   </fb:comments>            
   
  </div>        
 </div>

Comment: Now suddely 1 of the comments appeard

Comment: This is so wierd...some comments show..others dont